# Использование gmake

Tags: linux, unix, makefile, solaris

Мне посоветовали на http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/8726100?lastmod=1358421944338#comment-8731504 использовать `gmake` вместо `make` для инсталляции `openssh`. Установка `openssh` происходит в 3 шага:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Так вот у меня соответственно возник вопрос: что мне необходимо помимо установки самой `gmake` сделать дополнительно, чтобы использовать `gmake` при установке `openssh`, а именно необходимо ли в 3-х вышеперечисленных командах поменять `make` на `gmake` (я не знаю, как вызывается `gnu make` - командой `make` или `gmake`), нужно ли прописывать путь к `gmake` в `$PATH`? И если надо использовать команду `make` для вызова `gmake` при установке `openssh`, то как `linux` определит вызываю ли я старую программу `make` или новый установленный `gnu make`?

P.S. @avp вот `/volumes/openssh-6.1p1/Makefile`

```
# $Id: Makefile.in,v 1.326 2012/04/04 01:27:57 djm Exp $

# uncomment if you run a non bourne compatable shell. Ie. csh
#SHELL = /usr/gnu/bin/sh

AUTORECONF=autoreconf

prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
bindir=${exec_prefix}/bin
sbindir=${exec_prefix}/sbin
libexecdir=${exec_prefix}/libexec
datadir=${datarootdir}
datarootdir=${prefix}/share
mandir=${datarootdir}/man
mansubdir=man
sysconfdir=${prefix}/etc
piddir=/var/run
srcdir=.
top_srcdir=.

DESTDIR=

SSH_PROGRAM=${exec_prefix}/bin/ssh
ASKPASS_PROGRAM=$(libexecdir)/ssh-askpass
SFTP_SERVER=$(libexecdir)/sftp-server
SSH_KEYSIGN=$(libexecdir)/ssh-keysign
SSH_PKCS11_HELPER=$(libexecdir)/ssh-pkcs11-helper
PRIVSEP_PATH=/var/empty
SSH_PRIVSEP_USER=sshd
STRIP_OPT=-s

PATHS= -DSSHDIR=\"$(sysconfdir)\" \
    -D_PATH_SSH_PROGRAM=\"$(SSH_PROGRAM)\" \
    -D_PATH_SSH_ASKPASS_DEFAULT=\"$(ASKPASS_PROGRAM)\" \
    -D_PATH_SFTP_SERVER=\"$(SFTP_SERVER)\" \
    -D_PATH_SSH_KEY_SIGN=\"$(SSH_KEYSIGN)\" \
    -D_PATH_SSH_PKCS11_HELPER=\"$(SSH_PKCS11_HELPER)\" \
    -D_PATH_SSH_PIDDIR=\"$(piddir)\" \
    -D_PATH_PRIVSEP_CHROOT_DIR=\"$(PRIVSEP_PATH)\" \

CC=gcc
LD=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -O2 -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-builtin-memset -fstack-protector-all 
CPPFLAGS=-I. -I$(srcdir)  $(PATHS) -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
LIBS=-lresolv -lcrypto -lz -lsocket -lnsl 
SSHLIBS=
SSHDLIBS=
LIBEDIT=
AR=/usr/gnu/bin/ar
AWK=nawk
RANLIB=ranlib
INSTALL=/usr/gnu/bin/install -c
PERL=/usr/bin/perl
SED=/usr/gnu/bin/sed
ENT=
XAUTH_PATH=undefined
LDFLAGS=-L. -Lopenbsd-compat/  -fstack-protector-all
EXEEXT=
MANFMT=/usr/gnu/bin/nroff -mandoc

TARGETS=ssh$(EXEEXT) sshd$(EXEEXT) ssh-add$(EXEEXT) ssh-keygen$(EXEEXT) ssh-keyscan${EXEEXT} ssh-keysign${EXEEXT} ssh-pkcs11-helper$(EXEEXT) ssh-agent$(EXEEXT) scp$(EXEEXT) sftp-server$(EXEEXT) sftp$(EXEEXT)

LIBSSH_OBJS=acss.o authfd.o authfile.o bufaux.o bufbn.o buffer.o \
    canohost.o channels.o cipher.o cipher-acss.o cipher-aes.o \
    cipher-bf1.o cipher-ctr.o cipher-3des1.o cleanup.o \
    compat.o compress.o crc32.o deattack.o fatal.o hostfile.o \
    log.o match.o md-sha256.o moduli.o nchan.o packet.o \
    readpass.o rsa.o ttymodes.o xmalloc.o addrmatch.o \
    atomicio.o key.o dispatch.o kex.o mac.o uidswap.o uuencode.o misc.o \
    monitor_fdpass.o rijndael.o ssh-dss.o ssh-ecdsa.o ssh-rsa.o dh.o \
    kexdh.o kexgex.o kexdhc.o kexgexc.o bufec.o kexecdh.o kexecdhc.o \
    msg.o progressmeter.o dns.o entropy.o gss-genr.o umac.o jpake.o \
    schnorr.o ssh-pkcs11.o

SSHOBJS= ssh.o readconf.o clientloop.o sshtty.o \
    sshconnect.o sshconnect1.o sshconnect2.o mux.o \
    roaming_common.o roaming_client.o

SSHDOBJS=sshd.o auth-rhosts.o auth-passwd.o auth-rsa.o auth-rh-rsa.o \
    audit.o audit-bsm.o audit-linux.o platform.o \
    sshpty.o sshlogin.o servconf.o serverloop.o \
    auth.o auth1.o auth2.o auth-options.o session.o \
    auth-chall.o auth2-chall.o groupaccess.o \
    auth-skey.o auth-bsdauth.o auth2-hostbased.o auth2-kbdint.o \
    auth2-none.o auth2-passwd.o auth2-pubkey.o auth2-jpake.o \
    monitor_mm.o monitor.o monitor_wrap.o kexdhs.o kexgexs.o kexecdhs.o \
    auth-krb5.o \
    auth2-gss.o gss-serv.o gss-serv-krb5.o \
    loginrec.o auth-pam.o auth-shadow.o auth-sia.o md5crypt.o \
    sftp-server.o sftp-common.o \
    roaming_common.o roaming_serv.o \
    sandbox-null.o sandbox-rlimit.o sandbox-systrace.o sandbox-darwin.o \
    sandbox-seccomp-filter.o

MANPAGES    = moduli.5.out scp.1.out ssh-add.1.out ssh-agent.1.out ssh-keygen.1.out ssh-keyscan.1.out ssh.1.out sshd.8.out sftp-server.8.out sftp.1.out ssh-keysign.8.out ssh-pkcs11-helper.8.out sshd_config.5.out ssh_config.5.out
MANPAGES_IN = moduli.5 scp.1 ssh-add.1 ssh-agent.1 ssh-keygen.1 ssh-keyscan.1 ssh.1 sshd.8 sftp-server.8 sftp.1 ssh-keysign.8 ssh-pkcs11-helper.8 sshd_config.5 ssh_config.5
MANTYPE     = doc

CONFIGFILES=sshd_config.out ssh_config.out moduli.out
CONFIGFILES_IN=sshd_config ssh_config moduli

PATHSUBS    = \
    -e 's|/etc/ssh/ssh_config|$(sysconfdir)/ssh_config|g' \
    -e 's|/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts|$(sysconfdir)/ssh_known_hosts|g' \
    -e 's|/etc/ssh/sshd_config|$(sysconfdir)/sshd_config|g' \
    -e 's|/usr/libexec|$(libexecdir)|g' \
    -e 's|/etc/shosts.equiv|$(sysconfdir)/shosts.equiv|g' \
    -e 's|/etc/ssh/ssh_host_key|$(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_key|g' \
    -e 's|/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key|$(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_ecdsa_key|g' \
    -e 's|/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key|$(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_dsa_key|g' \
    -e 's|/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key|$(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_rsa_key|g' \
    -e 's|/var/run/sshd.pid|$(piddir)/sshd.pid|g' \
    -e 's|/etc/moduli|$(sysconfdir)/moduli|g' \
    -e 's|/etc/ssh/moduli|$(sysconfdir)/moduli|g' \
    -e 's|/etc/ssh/sshrc|$(sysconfdir)/sshrc|g' \
    -e 's|/usr/X11R6/bin/xauth|$(XAUTH_PATH)|g' \
    -e 's|/var/empty|$(PRIVSEP_PATH)|g' \
    -e 's|/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin|/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin|g'

FIXPATHSCMD = $(SED) $(PATHSUBS)

all: $(CONFIGFILES) $(MANPAGES) $(TARGETS)

$(LIBSSH_OBJS): Makefile.in config.h
$(SSHOBJS): Makefile.in config.h
$(SSHDOBJS): Makefile.in config.h

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<

LIBCOMPAT=openbsd-compat/libopenbsd-compat.a
$(LIBCOMPAT): always
    (cd openbsd-compat && $(MAKE))
always:

libssh.a: $(LIBSSH_OBJS)
    $(AR) rv $@ $(LIBSSH_OBJS)
    $(RANLIB) $@

ssh$(EXEEXT): $(LIBCOMPAT) libssh.a $(SSHOBJS)
    $(LD) -o $@ $(SSHOBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -lssh -lopenbsd-compat $(SSHLIBS) $(LIBS)

sshd$(EXEEXT): libssh.a $(LIBCOMPAT) $(SSHDOBJS)
    $(LD) -o $@ $(SSHDOBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -lssh -lopenbsd-compat $(SSHDLIBS) $(LIBS)

scp$(EXEEXT): $(LIBCOMPAT) libssh.a scp.o progressmeter.o
    $(LD) -o $@ scp.o progressmeter.o bufaux.o $(LDFLAGS) -lssh -lopenbsd-compat $(LIBS)

ssh-add$(EXEEXT): $(LIBCOMPAT) libssh.a ssh-add.o
    $(LD) -o $@ ssh-add.o $(LDFLAGS) -lssh -lopenbsd-compat $(LIBS)

ssh-agent$(EXEEXT): $(LIBCOMPAT) libssh.a ssh-agent.o ssh-pkcs11-client.o
    $(LD) -o $@ ssh-agent.o ssh-pkcs11-client.o $(LDFLAGS) -lssh -lopenbsd-compat $(LIBS)

ssh-keygen$(EXEEXT): $(LIBCOMPAT) libssh.a ssh-keygen.o
    $(LD) -o $@ ssh-keygen.o $(LDFLAGS) -lssh -lopenbsd-compat $(LIBS)

ssh-keysign$(EXEEXT): $(LIBCOMPAT) libssh.a ssh-keysign.o roaming_dummy.o readconf.o
    $(LD) -o $@ ssh-keysign.o readconf.o roaming_dummy.o $(LDFLAGS) -lssh -lopenbsd-compat $(LIBS)

ssh-pkcs11-helper$(EXEEXT): $(LIBCOMPAT) libssh.a ssh-pkcs11-helper.o ssh-pkcs11.o
    $(LD) -o $@ ssh-pkcs11-helper.o ssh-pkcs11.o $(LDFLAGS) -lssh -lopenbsd-compat -lssh -lopenbsd-compat $(LIBS)

ssh-keyscan$(EXEEXT): $(LIBCOMPAT) libssh.a ssh-keyscan.o roaming_dummy.o
    $(LD) -o $@ ssh-keyscan.o roaming_dummy.o $(LDFLAGS) -lssh -lopenbsd-compat -lssh $(LIBS)

sftp-server$(EXEEXT): $(LIBCOMPAT) libssh.a sftp.o sftp-common.o sftp-server.o sftp-server-main.o
    $(LD) -o $@ sftp-server.o sftp-common.o sftp-server-main.o $(LDFLAGS) -lssh -lopenbsd-compat $(LIBS)

sftp$(EXEEXT): $(LIBCOMPAT) libssh.a sftp.o sftp-client.o sftp-common.o sftp-glob.o progressmeter.o
    $(LD) -o $@ progressmeter.o sftp.o sftp-client.o sftp-common.o sftp-glob.o $(LDFLAGS) -lssh -lopenbsd-compat $(LIBS) $(LIBEDIT)

# test driver for the loginrec code - not built by default
logintest: logintest.o $(LIBCOMPAT) libssh.a loginrec.o
    $(LD) -o $@ logintest.o $(LDFLAGS) loginrec.o -lopenbsd-compat -lssh $(LIBS)

$(MANPAGES): $(MANPAGES_IN)
    if test "$(MANTYPE)" = "cat"; then \
        manpage=$(srcdir)/`echo $@ | sed 's/\.[1-9]\.out$$/\.0/'`; \
    else \
        manpage=$(srcdir)/`echo $@ | sed 's/\.out$$//'`; \
    fi; \
    if test "$(MANTYPE)" = "man"; then \
        $(FIXPATHSCMD) $${manpage} | $(AWK) -f $(srcdir)/mdoc2man.awk > $@; \
    else \
        $(FIXPATHSCMD) $${manpage} > $@; \
    fi

$(CONFIGFILES): $(CONFIGFILES_IN)
    conffile=`echo $@ | sed 's/.out$$//'`; \
    $(FIXPATHSCMD) $(srcdir)/$${conffile} > $@

# fake rule to stop make trying to compile moduli.o into a binary "moduli.o"
moduli:
    echo

clean:  regressclean
    rm -f *.o *.a $(TARGETS) logintest config.cache config.log
    rm -f *.out core survey
    (cd openbsd-compat && $(MAKE) clean)

distclean:  regressclean
    rm -f *.o *.a $(TARGETS) logintest config.cache config.log
    rm -f *.out core opensshd.init openssh.xml
    rm -f Makefile buildpkg.sh config.h config.status
    rm -f survey.sh openbsd-compat/regress/Makefile *~ 
    rm -rf autom4te.cache
    (cd openbsd-compat && $(MAKE) distclean)
    if test -d pkg ; then \
        rm -fr pkg ; \
    fi

veryclean: distclean
    rm -f configure config.h.in *.0

cleandir: veryclean

mrproper: veryclean

realclean: veryclean

catman-do:
    @for f in $(MANPAGES_IN) ; do \
        base=`echo $$f | sed 's/\..*$$//'` ; \
        echo "$$f -> $$base.0" ; \
        $(MANFMT) $$f | cat -v | sed -e 's/.\^H//g' \
            >$$base.0 ; \
    done

distprep: catman-do
    $(AUTORECONF)
    -rm -rf autom4te.cache

install: $(CONFIGFILES) $(MANPAGES) $(TARGETS) install-files install-sysconf host-key check-config
install-nokeys: $(CONFIGFILES) $(MANPAGES) $(TARGETS) install-files install-sysconf
install-nosysconf: $(CONFIGFILES) $(MANPAGES) $(TARGETS) install-files

check-config:
    -$(DESTDIR)$(sbindir)/sshd -t -f $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/sshd_config

install-files:
    $(srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
    $(srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(sbindir)
    $(srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)
    $(srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1
    $(srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)5
    $(srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)8
    $(srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(libexecdir)
    (umask 022 ; $(srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(PRIVSEP_PATH))
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 $(STRIP_OPT) ssh$(EXEEXT) $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/ssh$(EXEEXT)
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 $(STRIP_OPT) scp$(EXEEXT) $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/scp$(EXEEXT)
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 $(STRIP_OPT) ssh-add$(EXEEXT) $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/ssh-add$(EXEEXT)
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 $(STRIP_OPT) ssh-agent$(EXEEXT) $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/ssh-agent$(EXEEXT)
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 $(STRIP_OPT) ssh-keygen$(EXEEXT) $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/ssh-keygen$(EXEEXT)
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 $(STRIP_OPT) ssh-keyscan$(EXEEXT) $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/ssh-keyscan$(EXEEXT)
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 $(STRIP_OPT) sshd$(EXEEXT) $(DESTDIR)$(sbindir)/sshd$(EXEEXT)
    $(INSTALL) -m 4711 $(STRIP_OPT) ssh-keysign$(EXEEXT) $(DESTDIR)$(SSH_KEYSIGN)$(EXEEXT)
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 $(STRIP_OPT) ssh-pkcs11-helper$(EXEEXT) $(DESTDIR)$(SSH_PKCS11_HELPER)$(EXEEXT)
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 $(STRIP_OPT) sftp$(EXEEXT) $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/sftp$(EXEEXT)
    $(INSTALL) -m 0755 $(STRIP_OPT) sftp-server$(EXEEXT) $(DESTDIR)$(SFTP_SERVER)$(EXEEXT)
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 ssh.1.out $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/ssh.1
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 scp.1.out $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/scp.1
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 ssh-add.1.out $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/ssh-add.1
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 ssh-agent.1.out $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/ssh-agent.1
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 ssh-keygen.1.out $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/ssh-keygen.1
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 ssh-keyscan.1.out $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/ssh-keyscan.1
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 moduli.5.out $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)5/moduli.5
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 sshd_config.5.out $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)5/sshd_config.5
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 ssh_config.5.out $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)5/ssh_config.5
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 sshd.8.out $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)8/sshd.8
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 sftp.1.out $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/sftp.1
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 sftp-server.8.out $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)8/sftp-server.8
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 ssh-keysign.8.out $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)8/ssh-keysign.8
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 ssh-pkcs11-helper.8.out $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)8/ssh-pkcs11-helper.8
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/slogin
    ln -s ./ssh$(EXEEXT) $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/slogin
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/slogin.1
    ln -s ./ssh.1 $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/slogin.1

install-sysconf:
    if [ ! -d $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir) ]; then \
        $(srcdir)/mkinstalldirs $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir); \
    fi
    @if [ ! -f $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/ssh_config ]; then \
        $(INSTALL) -m 644 ssh_config.out $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/ssh_config; \
    else \
        echo "$(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/ssh_config already exists, install will not overwrite"; \
    fi
    @if [ ! -f $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/sshd_config ]; then \
        $(INSTALL) -m 644 sshd_config.out $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/sshd_config; \
    else \
        echo "$(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/sshd_config already exists, install will not overwrite"; \
    fi
    @if [ ! -f $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/moduli ]; then \
        if [ -f $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/primes ]; then \
            echo "moving $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/primes to $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/moduli"; \
            mv "$(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/primes" "$(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/moduli"; \
        else \
            $(INSTALL) -m 644 moduli.out $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/moduli; \
        fi ; \
    else \
        echo "$(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/moduli already exists, install will not overwrite"; \
    fi

host-key: ssh-keygen$(EXEEXT)
    @if [ -z "$(DESTDIR)" ] ; then \
        if [ -f "$(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_key" ] ; then \
            echo "$(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_key already exists, skipping." ; \
        else \
            ./ssh-keygen -t rsa1 -f $(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_key -N "" ; \
        fi ; \
        if [ -f $(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_dsa_key ] ; then \
            echo "$(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_dsa_key already exists, skipping." ; \
        else \
            ./ssh-keygen -t dsa -f $(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_dsa_key -N "" ; \
        fi ; \
        if [ -f $(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_rsa_key ] ; then \
            echo "$(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_rsa_key already exists, skipping." ; \
        else \
            ./ssh-keygen -t rsa -f $(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_rsa_key -N "" ; \
        fi ; \
        if [ -z "#no ecc#" ] ; then \
            if [ -f $(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_ecdsa_key ] ; then \
            echo "$(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_ecdsa_key already exists, skipping." ; \
            else \
            ./ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f $(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_ecdsa_key -N "" ; \
            fi ; \
        fi ; \
    fi ;

host-key-force: ssh-keygen$(EXEEXT)
    ./ssh-keygen -t rsa1 -f $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_key -N ""
    ./ssh-keygen -t dsa -f $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_dsa_key -N ""
    ./ssh-keygen -t rsa -f $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_rsa_key -N ""
    test -z "#no ecc#" && ./ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/ssh_host_ecdsa_key -N ""

uninstallall:   uninstall
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/ssh_config
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/sshd_config
    -rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)
    -rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)
    -rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(sbindir)
    -rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1
    -rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)8
    -rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)
    -rmdir $(DESTDIR)$(libexecdir)

uninstall:
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/slogin
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/ssh$(EXEEXT)
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/scp$(EXEEXT)
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/ssh-add$(EXEEXT)
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/ssh-agent$(EXEEXT)
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/ssh-keygen$(EXEEXT)
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/ssh-keyscan$(EXEEXT)
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/sftp$(EXEEXT)
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(sbindir)/sshd$(EXEEXT)
    -rm -r $(DESTDIR)$(SFTP_SERVER)$(EXEEXT)
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(SSH_KEYSIGN)$(EXEEXT)
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(SSH_PKCS11_HELPER)$(EXEEXT)
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/ssh.1
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/scp.1
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/ssh-add.1
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/ssh-agent.1
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/ssh-keygen.1
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/sftp.1
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/ssh-keyscan.1
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)8/sshd.8
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)8/sftp-server.8
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)8/ssh-keysign.8
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)8/ssh-pkcs11-helper.8
    -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(mandir)/$(mansubdir)1/slogin.1

tests interop-tests:    $(TARGETS)
    BUILDDIR=`pwd`; \
    [ -d `pwd`/regress ]  ||  mkdir -p `pwd`/regress; \
    [ -f `pwd`/regress/Makefile ]  || \
        ln -s `cd $(srcdir) && pwd`/regress/Makefile `pwd`/regress/Makefile ; \
    TEST_SHELL="sh"; \
    TEST_SSH_SSH="$${BUILDDIR}/ssh"; \
    TEST_SSH_SSHD="$${BUILDDIR}/sshd"; \
    TEST_SSH_SSHAGENT="$${BUILDDIR}/ssh-agent"; \
    TEST_SSH_SSHADD="$${BUILDDIR}/ssh-add"; \
    TEST_SSH_SSHKEYGEN="$${BUILDDIR}/ssh-keygen"; \
    TEST_SSH_SSHPKCS11HELPER="$${BUILDDIR}/ssh-pkcs11-helper"; \
    TEST_SSH_SSHKEYSCAN="$${BUILDDIR}/ssh-keyscan"; \
    TEST_SSH_SFTP="$${BUILDDIR}/sftp"; \
    TEST_SSH_SFTPSERVER="$${BUILDDIR}/sftp-server"; \
    TEST_SSH_PLINK="plink"; \
    TEST_SSH_PUTTYGEN="puttygen"; \
    TEST_SSH_CONCH="conch"; \
    TEST_SSH_IPV6="yes" ; \
    TEST_SSH_ECC="no" ; \
    TEST_SSH_SHA256="yes" ; \
    cd $(srcdir)/regress || exit $$?; \
    $(MAKE) \
        .OBJDIR="$${BUILDDIR}/regress" \
        .CURDIR="`pwd`" \
        BUILDDIR="$${BUILDDIR}" \
        OBJ="$${BUILDDIR}/regress/" \
        PATH="$${BUILDDIR}:$${PATH}" \
        TEST_SHELL="$${TEST_SHELL}" \
        TEST_SSH_SSH="$${TEST_SSH_SSH}" \
        TEST_SSH_SSHD="$${TEST_SSH_SSHD}" \
        TEST_SSH_SSHAGENT="$${TEST_SSH_SSHAGENT}" \
        TEST_SSH_SSHADD="$${TEST_SSH_SSHADD}" \
        TEST_SSH_SSHKEYGEN="$${TEST_SSH_SSHKEYGEN}" \
        TEST_SSH_SSHPKCS11HELPER="$${TEST_SSH_SSHPKCS11HELPER}" \
        TEST_SSH_SSHKEYSCAN="$${TEST_SSH_SSHKEYSCAN}" \
        TEST_SSH_SFTP="$${TEST_SSH_SFTP}" \
        TEST_SSH_SFTPSERVER="$${TEST_SSH_SFTPSERVER}" \
        TEST_SSH_PLINK="$${TEST_SSH_PLINK}" \
        TEST_SSH_PUTTYGEN="$${TEST_SSH_PUTTYGEN}" \
        TEST_SSH_CONCH="$${TEST_SSH_CONCH}" \
        TEST_SSH_IPV6="$${TEST_SSH_IPV6}" \
        TEST_SSH_ECC="$${TEST_SSH_ECC}" \
        TEST_SSH_SHA256="$${TEST_SSH_SHA256}" \
        EXEEXT="$(EXEEXT)" \
        $@ && echo all tests passed

compat-tests: $(LIBCOMPAT)
    (cd openbsd-compat/regress && $(MAKE))

regressclean:
    if [ -f regress/Makefile ] && [ -r regress/Makefile ]; then \
        (cd regress && $(MAKE) clean) \
    fi

survey: survey.sh ssh
    @$(SHELL) ./survey.sh > survey
    @echo 'The survey results have been placed in the file "survey" in the'
    @echo 'current directory.  Please review the file then send with'
    @echo '"make send-survey".'

send-survey:    survey
    mail portable-survey@mindrot.org <survey

package: $(CONFIGFILES) $(MANPAGES) $(TARGETS)
    if [ "yes" = yes ]; then \
        sh buildpkg.sh; \
    fi
```

P.S.2. @avp файл `/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key` и `/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub` появились. В результате повторного выполнения `make install` выдало

```
(cd openbsd-compat && make)
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/bin
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/sbin
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/man
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/man/man1
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/man/man5
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/man/man8
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/libexec
(umask 022 ; ./mkinstalldirs /var/empty)
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh /usr/local/bin/ssh
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s scp /usr/local/bin/scp
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-add /usr/local/bin/ssh-add
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-agent /usr/local/bin/ssh-agent
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-keygen /usr/local/bin/ssh-keygen
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-keyscan /usr/local/bin/ssh-keyscan
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s sshd /usr/local/sbin/sshd
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 4711 -s ssh-keysign /usr/local/libexec/ssh-keysign
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-pkcs11-helper /usr/local/libexec/ssh-pkcs11-helper
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s sftp /usr/local/bin/sftp
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s sftp-server /usr/local/libexec/sftp-server
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 scp.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/scp.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-add.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-add.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-agent.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-agent.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-keygen.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-keygen.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-keyscan.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-keyscan.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 moduli.5.out /usr/local/share/man/man5/moduli.5
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 sshd_config.5.out /usr/local/share/man/man5/sshd_config.5
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh_config.5.out /usr/local/share/man/man5/ssh_config.5
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 sshd.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/sshd.8
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 sftp.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/sftp.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 sftp-server.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/sftp-server.8
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-keysign.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/ssh-keysign.8
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-pkcs11-helper.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/ssh-pkcs11-helper.8
rm -f /usr/local/bin/slogin
ln -s ./ssh /usr/local/bin/slogin
rm -f /usr/local/share/man/man1/slogin.1
ln -s ./ssh.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/slogin.1
if [ ! -d /usr/local/etc ]; then \
    ./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/etc; \
fi
/usr/local/etc/ssh_config already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/sshd_config already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/moduli already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_key already exists, skipping.
/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key already exists, skipping.
sh: line 14: 23798: Memory fault(coredump)
*** Signal 11 - core dumped
The following command caused the error:
if [ -z "" ] ; then \
    if [ -f "/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_key" ] ; then \
        echo "/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_key already exists, skipping." ; \
    else \
        ./ssh-keygen -t rsa1 -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_key -N "" ; \
    fi ; \
    if [ -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key ] ; then \
        echo "/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key already exists, skipping." ; \
    else \
        ./ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key -N "" ; \
    fi ; \
    if [ -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key ] ; then \
        echo "/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key already exists, skipping." ; \
    else \
        ./ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key -N "" ; \
    fi ; \
    if [ -z "#no ecc#" ] ; then \
        if [ -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key ] ; then \
        echo "/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key already exists, skipping." ; \
        else \
        ./ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key -N "" ; \
        fi ; \
    fi ; \
fi ;
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `host-key'
```

P.S.3. @avp после очередного выполнения `make install` выдало

```
(cd openbsd-compat && make)
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/bin
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/sbin
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/man
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/man/man1
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/man/man5
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/share/man/man8
./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/libexec
(umask 022 ; ./mkinstalldirs /var/empty)
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh /usr/local/bin/ssh
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s scp /usr/local/bin/scp
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-add /usr/local/bin/ssh-add
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-agent /usr/local/bin/ssh-agent
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-keygen /usr/local/bin/ssh-keygen
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-keyscan /usr/local/bin/ssh-keyscan
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s sshd /usr/local/sbin/sshd
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 4711 -s ssh-keysign /usr/local/libexec/ssh-keysign
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh-pkcs11-helper /usr/local/libexec/ssh-pkcs11-helper
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s sftp /usr/local/bin/sftp
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s sftp-server /usr/local/libexec/sftp-server
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 scp.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/scp.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-add.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-add.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-agent.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-agent.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-keygen.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-keygen.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-keyscan.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/ssh-keyscan.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 moduli.5.out /usr/local/share/man/man5/moduli.5
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 sshd_config.5.out /usr/local/share/man/man5/sshd_config.5
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh_config.5.out /usr/local/share/man/man5/ssh_config.5
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 sshd.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/sshd.8
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 sftp.1.out /usr/local/share/man/man1/sftp.1
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 sftp-server.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/sftp-server.8
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-keysign.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/ssh-keysign.8
/usr/gnu/bin/install -c -m 644 ssh-pkcs11-helper.8.out /usr/local/share/man/man8/ssh-pkcs11-helper.8
rm -f /usr/local/bin/slogin
ln -s ./ssh /usr/local/bin/slogin
rm -f /usr/local/share/man/man1/slogin.1
ln -s ./ssh.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/slogin.1
if [ ! -d /usr/local/etc ]; then \
    ./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/etc; \
fi
/usr/local/etc/ssh_config already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/sshd_config already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/moduli already exists, install will not overwrite
/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_key already exists, skipping.
/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key already exists, skipping.
/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key already exists, skipping.
/usr/local/sbin/sshd -t -f /usr/local/etc/sshd_config
Privilege separation user sshd does not exist
*** Error code 255 (ignored)
```

Comment: @avp вы имеете ввиду `man ssh`?

Comment: @ivan31, вообще-то я говорил о sshd, но этот man очевидно тоже надо читать, как и большинство из SEE ALSO в них.

Видите

    Privilege separation user sshd does not exist

? 

IMHO это говорит о том, что настройки юзеров ssh-у не нравятся. Какие они **должны быть**, где и как что-то надо прописать я не знаю.

Comment: @avp, я восстановил снимок и выполнил команду

    root@one: /usr/local/bin# ./ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key -N ""
Первоначально выдало
    
    Segmentation Fault(core dumped)
Затем повторил эту команду и она отработала нормально, а потом выполнил команду

    root@one: /usr/local/bin# echo $?
на что мне выдало код возврата

    root@one: 0
А насчет проблемы 

    Privilege separation user sshd does not exist
я ввел ее в google и одной из ссылок вернуло http://www.citi.umich.edu/u/provos/ssh/privsep-faq.html .

Comment: @avp, я ввел ее в google и одной из ссылок вернуло http://www.citi.umich.edu/u/provos/ssh/privsep-faq.html, только я не знаю не помешает ли предлагаемое там решение проблемы настройке `hadoop`кластера.

Comment: @ivan31, вот с проблемами hadoop я точно не знаком, но не думаю, что наличие юзера sshd и группы sshd может кому-то помешать.

Кстати, по поводу аналогичной проблемы со сборкой и Segmentation Fault можете почитать [здесь](http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2010-February/028237.html)

Comment: @avp ранее я не правильно вводил `echo $?` без `?`. Сейчас я ввел правильно и вернуло 0 (елси это конечно что-то дает).

Answer (score 3):

[@ivan31](/users/4705/ivan31), IMHO из

```
/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_key already exists, skipping.
sh: line 9: 19705: Memory fault(coredump)
*** Signal 11 - core dumped
The following command caused the error:
if [ -z "" ] ; then \
    if [ -f "/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_key" ] ; then \
        echo "/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_key already exists, skipping." ; \
    else \
        ./ssh-keygen -t rsa1 -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_key -N "" ; \
    fi ; \
    if [ -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key ] ; then \
        echo "/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key already exists, skipping." ; \
    else \
        ./ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key -N "" ; \
    fi ; \
    ....
```

совсем не следует, что надо менять make.

**Валится-то внутри sh**

Я бы во первых посмотрел, есть ли файл `/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key` (текст предыдущей проверки мы видим

```
/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_key already exists, skipping.
```

и на этом все. Дальше ошибка), а  затем запустил руками

```
./ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key -N ""
```

и посмотрел код возврата и т.п.

Comment: @avp, файла `/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key` нет.

Comment: @avp, команда 

    root@one: /usr/local/bin# ./ssh-keygen - t dsa -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key -N ""
ничего не выдало и в результате отобразилась строка приглашения

   root@one: /usr/local/bin#

Comment: Ну, а какой код результата?

    echo $?

Хотя, это уже поздно узнавать. Файл `/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key` появился?

Попробуйте make еще раз. Пройдет или нет. Если нет, то где и с какой диагностикой?

Comment: @avp, про какой код результата вы говорите? Чтобы получить код результата мне надо выполнить `./ssh-keygen - t dsa -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key -N ""` или же надо выполнить команду `echo $./ssh-keygen - t dsa -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key -N ""` (какую команду надо выполнить чтобы получить код результата, я могу это сделать, восстановив снимок виртуальной машины и заново установив `openssh` (так как текущий снимок отличается тоько этим), а затем после установки смогу получить код результата команды, которую вы укажите)?

Comment: Я имел в виду результат `ssh-keygen` т.е.

    ssh-keygen ...
    echo $?
    
echo напечатает код завершения ssh-keygen. Не думаю, что есть смысл настолько углубляться в это, чтобы откатывать VM.

Файл-то (/usr/local/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key) у Вас появился? Если да, запустите make еше раз. Должен сказать, что-то вроде

    ... already exists, skipping.

И посмоьрите что будет дальше. В конце-то концов какую-то часть Makefile можно сделать руками, потом выбросить "сбойные" куски и выполнить остаток.

Ведь Ваша цель установить этот openssh-6.1?

Comment: @avp моя цель - установить `openssh`, чтобы использовать его функциональность для настройки `hadoop`-кластера (связь между компьютерами кластера). Мне удалось добиться правильного выполнения `hadoop`-программы на одном компьютере, на что было потрачено немалое время и поэтому, чтобы добиться правильной установки `openssh` для полноценного функционирования `hadoop`-кластера я готов даже откатить `VM` и получить код возврата, если эта информация поможет определить причину ошибки, тем более я кроме `openssh` ничего не теряю, который я всегда могу снова перекинуть с основного компьютера на `VM`.

Comment: @avp см. P.S.3. в вопросе о результате очередного выполнения `make install`.

Comment: @ivan31, вот по этому сообщению    

    /usr/local/sbin/sshd -t -f /usr/local/etc/sshd_config
    Privilege separation user sshd does not exist
    *** Error code 255 (ignored)

похоже, что install в основном прошел (или какая-то часть прошла) и был запущен ssh демон в режиме тестирования (ключик **-t**). Что-то в конфигурации ему не нравится, но там man очень длинный. 

Попробуйте сами с конфигурацией (права и т.п.) разобраться или соответствующую тему (только не пишите в ней о gmake и особенно о hadoop) откройте.

Answer (score 2):

Версию make можно узнать запуском команды с параметром --version:

```
make --version
```

Для GNU-версии команды make вывод команды должен содержать строчку  `GNU Make 3.82`

make - это дефолтный для данной системы сборщик, у BSD он свой, у Solaris, возможно, тоже.
gmake - имя аналогичной программы, разработанной в рамках проекта GNU, в Linux по умолчанию установлен именно он, поэтому он называется *make*.

Если нужно собирать программу именно gmake, в командной строке в Linux нужно писать *make*, в других ОС надо устанавливать его из пакетов/портов и в консоли явно необходимо вызывать его - *gmake*.

Comment: @dred, на 

    make --version
выдало

    make: Warning: Ignoring DistributedMake -v option
    make: Warning: Ignoring DistributedMake -o option
    make: Fatal error: No dmake output dir argument after -o flag
 У меня операционная система `Nexenta` - http://www.nexenta.com/corp/, http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexenta_OS.