# Использование gmake непосредственно из папки установки

Tags: linux, unix, makefile, solaris

Я знаю, что бинарные файлы `gmake` были установлены в папку `/usr/local/bin`. Пытаясь выполнить скрипт `make` непосредственно из этой папки я запустил команду

```
root@one: /usr/local/bin# ./make /volumes/openssh-6.1p1/Makefile
```

для выполнения второго шага установки `openssh` (см. [Использование gmake](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/184447/linux-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-gmake)), после того как сделал `./configure`.
В результате получил сообщения

```
make: Warning: File `/volumes/openssh-6.1p1/Makefile' has modification time 39006 s in the future
make: Nothing to be done for `/volumes/openssh-6.1p1/Makefile'.
make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
```

Какую команду надо выполнить с `gmake` из папки `/usr/local/bin` с бинарником `make`, чтобы произвести второй шаг установки `openssh`?

Comment: А запуск из каталога, где лежит Makefile, работает? Если да, зачем извращаться, ну не предусмотрели авторы Makefile этого. Если нет, ваша проблема не в каталоге, а в чём-то другом.

Comment: @VladD просто `make` в каталоге с `Makefile` работает.

Comment: @ivan31: а в чём тогда проблема? Подходите прагматично. Ну ошибка в Makefile, не предусмотрели этот случай. Сообщите авторам баг-репорт.

Answer (score 1):

А чем не устраивает

```
cd /volumes/openssh-6.1p1/ && make
```

?

Ну или

```
cd /volumes/openssh-6.1p1/ && /usr/local/bin/make
```